# Checkout using CSOM does not prevent update/rename/deletion

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to prevent any data change for a file using CSOM, but even after checking out the file, the UI still allows update/deletion/rename. Is there a way to prevent this, i e to lock/checkout the file so that it could not be editing in any way?

My code looks like this:

```
          SPClient.File newFile =
                context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(serverRelative);

            context.Load(newFile, f => f.CheckOutType);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            if (newFile.CheckOutType == SPClient.CheckOutType.None)
            {
                newFile.CheckOut();                    
                context.Load(newFile);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by performing a `Load` immediately after you call `CheckOut()`, you are erasing your checkout.

When you call `Checkout()` from CSOM, it does not take affect until you call `ExecuteQuery()`.  But whenever you call `Load(someobj)`, the next call to `ExecuteQuery()` will load that object's existing server-side properties into your client-side copy, erasing any changes you may have made to the client-side object.  It's kind of the equivalent of starting to fill out an online form, then refreshing the page before you hit the submit button.

Try changing to:

```
SPClient.File newFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(serverRelative);

context.Load(newFile, f => f.CheckOutType);
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (newFile.CheckOutType == SPClient.CheckOutType.None)
{
    newFile.CheckOut();   
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```